# I have installed the latest version of laravel Laravel Framework 7.0-dev

Tags: php, laravel

I want to enable authentication in the latest version? I am trying to enable auth by running below given commands

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

But I am facing the below-given issue after running the composer command to install the package.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - laravel/ui 1.x-dev requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - laravel/ui v1.1.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - laravel/ui v1.1.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - laravel/ui v1.1.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, 7.x-dev].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui ^1.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[1.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a release of laravel/ui that works with Laravel 7 (since that's also not officially released. You may need to require the master branch of laravel/ui. Also Laravel UI is just boilerplates, you don't need it to enable auth

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. As I am new to laravel can you please guide me how to make master branch of laravel/ui required in my latest version(7.0-dev) for enabling auth(Login and Registration related functionalites)?
@apokryfos

Comment: If you're new to laravel I suggest you use version 6.x (currently it's 6.9) which is officially supported and works with laravel ui

Comment: Okay, I am using laravel installer command to download. Is there any way to download laravel with version 6.9? If I am downloading it with command [laravel new project_name] then it is installing with latest version.

Comment: If you install using `laravel new project_name --dev` you would get Laravel 7. If you install it without that it should install Laravel 6.2 . It doesn't seem like it's working as I'd expect it to be honest since laravel switched to semver but it is what it is. Maybe just manually change your `composer.json` to get version `^6` and install again. Running as `laravel new project_name --auth` might be even better

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I will try that.

Comment: Version 6.9 is installed by downloading it through composer! Thank you